# Homebrew PATH zprofile / zshrc:export:1: not valid in this context

Tags: path, export, homebrew, zshrc

WHEN I OPEN MY TERMINAL I HAVE THIS MESSAGE:
/Users/emvlp/.zprofile:export:1: not valid in this context: PATH/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

/Users/emvlp/.zshrc:export:1: not valid in this context: Support/Coursier/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin

I already **have installed Homebrew**in :  which brew = /usr/local/bin/brew
and i already uninstalled Anaconda.

/usr/bin/nano ~/.**zshrc**    =
export PATH=/Users/emvlp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/emvlp/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/emvlp/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/emvlp/.daml/bin:/Users/emvlp/.daml/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/emvlp/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin -
export PATH=/Users/emvlp/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/emvlp/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/emvlp/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/emvlp/.daml/bin:/Users/emvlp/.daml/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/emvlp/Library/Application:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin

/usr/bin/nano ~/.**zprofile**

export PATH"/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"

how can i fix this long PATH i have in ZSHRC ? Should i delete some part of the "export" in both places zshrc and zprofile?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is so poorly formatted it is unintelligible.